# Why does Save Chart function work so differently across browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, download, cross-browser

I am using the following function to allow the user to save an image. (Half the charts they might want to save as image are hidden, so they can't right click on them. They're displayed instead as SVGs.) I also want download-as-image options available for those who don't know about right clicking on images.

This is all working perfectly in my text editor & Chrome. I click the button with the saveChart function attached and the file downloads. In Safari a new tab opens at the URL - not the behaviour I want but understandable. I can't test on IE. But on Firefox nothing happens at all. It's as though i haven't pressed the button.

JS is enabled and works on other buttons / functions.

```
function saveChart(obj) {

    var tempStr = obj.parentNode.id;
    var newID = Number(tempStr.substr(6,tempStr.length-6));

    var a  = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = 'charts/chart'+newID+'.png';
    a.download = 'image.png';

    a.click();
}
```

Is the difference caused by user security settings and if so what are they? Is there any way to secure the same (download) behaviour cross-browser?

Thanks

Emma

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: no, no errors showing